# Trying to remember an adjective used to describe code that does not depend on one particular implementation

Tags: terminology

It's on the tip of my tongue!

I remember it's also used to describe code that doesn't care about the contents of the data it moves around. The word could also have had some religious connotations but I'm not sure.

Comment: Abstraction? Inversion of Control? Interfaces?

Comment: I think it might be "agnostic" but to be honest I've spent too long looking for the answer and words don't look like anything anymore.

Comment: `Data agnostic` is certainly a widely used term.